# Splitting a list of twitter data

Tags: python, list, twitter, split

I have a file full of hundreds of un-separated tweets all formatted like so:

```
{"text": "Just posted a photo @ Navarre Conference Center", "created_at": "Sun  Nov 13 01:52:03 +0000 2016", "coordinates": [-86.8586,  30.40299]}
```

I am trying to split them up so I can assign each part to a variable.

1. The text
2. The timestamp
3. The location coordinates

I was able to split the tweets up using `.split('{}')` but I don't really know how to split the rest into the three things that I want.

My basic idea that didn't work:

```
file = open('tweets_with_time.json' , 'r')
line = file.readline()

    for line in file:


        line = line.split(',')

        message = (line[0])
        timestamp = (line[1])
        position = (line[2])

        #just to test if it's working
        print(position)
```

Thanks!

Comment: i don’t think you can split on `{}` so try splitting on `,`

Comment: and then split on `:`.. but idk i’m not sure cus not at computer to try

Comment: I don't see how `line.split('{}')` could work on that data.

Comment: Changed to a comma. It does about the same thing but organizes it better for sure.

Comment: but on second thought there is probably already a JSON parsing lib or func to do it for you

Comment: there is... `json.load`...

Comment: Is each tweet on a separate line of the `'tweets_with_time.json'` file? Does each line end with a `}`, or does it end in a comma? It would be easier to work with if that was proper JSON, with those dicts stored inside a list. But either way, you should be using the standard `json` module to parse this data.

Comment: The file has has all the tweets side by side. All of the text in the above example starts and ends with {} with no space between one and the next.

Comment: Are you saying that there's only one line in the file, and that line has 100s of tweets on it?

Comment: Each line of your file has tweet JSONs like this?

Comment: Essentially. I have managed to split the line into each individual tweet but I am having trouble properly splitting each tweet into those 3 categories I listed.

Comment: You should slap whoever created that file. If _you_ created it, slap yourself. Twice. ;)

Comment: Is that even valid JSON..? It should be in a list `[]` with the curly braces `{}` separated by a comma.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19I14FhRata1HFf0rO-tNI0qCx2d449YC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: 3 people (including myself) immediately answered this question with the JSON module... haha

Comment: Ok. That file _isn't_ valid JSON, but each line of the file is valid JSON, so we can easily parse it using the `json` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded your file, it's not as bad as you said. Each tweet is on a separate line. It would be nicer if the file was a JSON list, but we can still parse it fairly easily, line by line. Here's an example that extracts the 1st 10 tweets.

```
import json

fname = 'tweets_with_time.json'
with open(fname) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        # Convert this JSON line into a Python dict
        data = json.loads(line)

        # Extract the data
        message = data['text']
        timestamp = data['created_at']
        position = data['coordinates']

        # Print it
        print(i)
        print('Message:', message)
        print('Timestamp:', timestamp)
        print('Position:', position)
        print()

        #Only print the first 10 tweets
        if i == 10:
            break
```

Unfortunately, I can't show the output of this script: Stack Exchange won't allow me to put those shortened URLs into a post.

---

Here's a modified version that cuts off each message at the URL.

```
import json

fname = 'tweets_with_time.json'
with open(fname) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        # Convert this JSON line to a Python dict
        data = json.loads(line)

        # Extract the data
        message = data['text']
        timestamp = data['created_at']
        position = data['coordinates']

        # Remove the URL from the message
        idx = message.find('https://')
        if idx != -1:
            message = message[:idx]

        # Print it
        print(i)
        print('Message:', message)
        print('Timestamp:', timestamp)
        print('Position:', position)
        print()

        #Only print the first 10 tweets
        if i == 10:
            break
```

**output**

```
1
Message: Just posted a photo @ Navarre Conference Center 
Timestamp: Sun Nov 13 01:52:03 +0000 2016
Position: [-86.8586, 30.40299]

2
Message: I don't usually drink #coffee, but I do love a good #Vietnamese drip coffee with condense milk… 
Timestamp: Sun Nov 13 01:52:04 +0000 2016
Position: [-123.04437109, 49.26211779]

3
Message: #bestcurry☝✈️✝#johanvanaarde #kauai #rugby #surfing… 
Timestamp: Sun Nov 13 01:52:04 +0000 2016
Position: [-159.4958861, 22.20321232]

4
Message: #thatonePerezwedding  @ Scenic Springs 
Timestamp: Sun Nov 13 01:52:05 +0000 2016
Position: [-98.68685568, 29.62182898]

5
Message: Miami trends now: Heat, Wade, VeteransDay, OneLetterOffBands and TheyMightBeACatfishIf. 
Timestamp: Sun Nov 13 01:52:05 +0000 2016
Position: [-80.19240081, 25.78111669]

6
Message: Thank you family for supporting my efforts. I love you all!… 
Timestamp: Sun Nov 13 01:52:05 +0000 2016
Position: [-117.83012, 33.65558157]

7
Message: If you're looking for work in #HONOLULU, HI, check out this #job: 
Timestamp: Sun Nov 13 01:52:05 +0000 2016
Position: [-157.7973653, 21.2868901]

8
Message: Drinking a L'Brett d'Apricot by @CrookedStave @ FOBAB — 
Timestamp: Sun Nov 13 01:52:05 +0000 2016
Position: [-87.6455, 41.8671]

9
Message: Can you recommend anyone for this #job? Barista (US) - 
Timestamp: Sun Nov 13 01:52:05 +0000 2016
Position: [-121.9766823, 38.350109]

10
Message: He makes me happy @ Frank and Bank 
Timestamp: Sun Nov 13 01:52:05 +0000 2016
Position: [-75.69360487, 45.41268776]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like well-formatted JSON data. Try the following:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

file_ptr = open('tweets_with_time.json' , 'r')
data = json.load(file_ptr)
pprint(data)
```

It should parse your data into a nice Python dictionary. You can access the elements by their names like:

```
# Return the first 'coordinates' data point as a list of floats
data[0]["coordinates"]

# Return the 5th 'text' data point as a string
data[4]["text"]
```

Comment: No, that won't work with the OP's data. It's not a single JSON object, it's got one object per line.